I can still edit comments on deleted posts
Apparently I can edit a comment on a post that I deleted:


From the GIF, you didn't delete the comment. If you had deleted the comment, it would not be shown at all, unless you're a moderator and explicitly show deleted comments. The post is deleted. Comments on deleted posts can be edited or deleted during the normal timeframes for those actions. This is not a bug. It is [tag:status-bydesign].

@Makyen think I see the confusion here though. The text does say "Comments disabled on deleted posts", and "disabled" might also mean that existing comments can't be edited. Perhaps a feature request to change that message is due, though not sure what would be better. Maybe "New comments can't be added on deleted posts" - but anyway will leave it for a feature request, if such will get posted.

@ShadowWizard While there might be confusion, that's not what's being reported in this question. For non-moderators, that "confusion" will last for at most the 5 minute grace period during which the user can edit a comment, if the post gets deleted within that initial five minutes from posting the comment. Admittedly, that text would probably be better as "Adding comments is disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews", but that's not what this question is asking/reporting. [Note: there are other edge cases, at least for moderators, where that text is presented inaccurately.]

As per always, you can't edit a comment once the five minutes have expired. Being the author of the comment, you can delete that whenever you see fit and proper.

The comment is not deleted, hence you can edit it.
The fact the post under which the comment is posted is deleted is not relevant.
I don't see any bug in this behavior.
